# In Python I can't open some png images properly using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, png, jpeg

I have two png images and if i try to open them (here is the code)

```
from PIL import Image 

x = Image.open('png/x-tictactoe.png')
o = Image.open('png/o-tictactoe.png')
print(x)
print(o)
```

The first line opens the image normally as png, while the second line one automatically opens the image as jpeg

Here is the output:

```
"C:\Users\Delfino De Chicchis\PycharmProjects\TicTacToe\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Delfino De Chicchis/PycharmProjects/TicTacToe/test.py"
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=860x898 at 0x27FA46330A0>
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=L size=880x1004 at 0x27FA67E8C10>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I just want to open both files as png, in order to use RGBA to make transparent background.

Someone could help me please?

Comment: Are you sure that both files are png's, and not just a jpeg file with a png extension? If you're on linux or mac, try `file imagename.png` and see what the response is

Comment: I'm on windows, but i've checked in properties, and it says file PNG(.png)

Comment: Try uploading your *"unhappy"* file here and checking the first few bytes https://hexed.it

Comment: ok, I did but don't know what I should look at.

Comment: A PNG file will begin with `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`. A JPEG will begin with `ff d8 ff`.

Comment: Oh ok you're right, so the file extension is not enough to say what's the actual type? By the way, thank you and sorry for the dumb question. How can I give you the right answer since this is a comment?

Comment: It's late here. I'll write it up as a proper answer tomorrow. Glad it worked. And "no", the file extension is not really very indicative, it is just a Windows convention.

Comment: I have written it up now as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension of a file is not necessarily a proper indicator of its content - it is just a Windows concept. Most files have a [recognisable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) *"magic number"*, or *"signature"*, at the start.

So, try dumping the contents your *"unhappy"* PNG file in hex, or opening it in an online hex editor like [hexedit](https://hexed.it) if you don't have a locally-installed hex tool available.

For PNG, you should see a valid [PNG signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) like this:

```
89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a ... (in ASCII 50="P", 4e="N", 47="G")
```

For JPEG, you should see a valid [JPEG signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), like this:

```
ff d8 ff ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `display(x) and display(o)`  If not working check the directories.

Comment: it normally opens images

Comment: Go to the file right click the to properties. Go to generat and check the location of the image.

Comment: they have the right path, indeed i can normally use both but can't change trasparency of jpeg

Comment: Use :display( x ) Instead of:  print( x )

Comment: from IPython module? It shows up same things

Comment: @DelfinoDeChicchis Are you using https://colab.research.google.com doing this?